# Can I use reflection to convert a generic .NET DLL into one that works with Silverlight? What tool should I use?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, reflection, port

I have a DLL that I don't have source code to, but I want to use it in Silverlight.

Disregarding the dependency issue, what tool should I use to reflect into the DLL, get the source code, and convert it to a SL library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reflector tool ought to suffice.  Red Gate's Reflector has [an add-in available](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) that will reconstruct all of the original class files for you, assuming there is sufficient metadata available, and the DLL is not otherwise obfuscated.

Comment: Based on Denis Bauer's lovely addin (in your link) I have created a Reflector addin that will dump all/selected DLLs (instead of just one DLL at a time). I will get a version on my blog as soon as I get it writing out a solution file as well (it currently just writes out all the projects).